# Java Collections Generics <? extends Employee> throwing exception

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have written below code

```
class Student {}
class Student1 extends Student {}
class Student2 extends Student {}
List<? extends Student> emp = new ArrayList<>();
emp.add(new Student()); // I do not want this to happen. at compile time it should give me error
emp.add(new Student1()); // this should happen
emp.add(new Student2()); // this should happen
```

But in above code its not working throwing compile error in all 3 adds.

Any pointers?

Comment: Why are you using a wildcard (`?`) here?

Comment: Can you make Student Abstract?

Comment: I want to add only subclass class objects of student in this list(emp) not the Student object. I have used wildcard from that reason but that might be wrong searching for correct way of doing this.

Comment: You can't do this... And it's an odd requirement to start with - what's the benefit here?

Comment: Nope I can not make it abstract. @Jon - Its just of learning. Then can anyone tell me what is the use of <? extends Student> its valid right as no error there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such option in Java to constrain the type parameter to *just subtypes* of a given type. It looks like you have taken the meaning of the syntax `? extends Type` a bit too literally. `Type` there is the *upper bound* of the wildcard, and the bounds are always inclusive.

If your idea was the way it really worked, there would be no type by which you could refer to a general item of your list: the narrowest such type is `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

In java Generics are not co-variant. So `List<T>` is not a sub-type of `List<S>` if `T` is a sub-type of `S`. This was done to ensure static, compile time type safety. If it were allowed you could do things like following:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> numberList = intList;
numberList.add(1.0); // Breaks the contract that intList will contain only Integers 
                     // (or Objects of classes derived from Integer class)
```

Now to allow functions which could work on Lists containing anything which extends some base class, Bounded wildcards were introduced. So for example, if you wish to write a generic add method which returns the sum of all elements in a `List` (irrespective of whether the list if of Type `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`), you can write the following code

```
double add(List<? extends Number> numberList) {
    double ans = 0;
    for (Number num : numberList) {
        ans += num.doubleValue();
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The argument can be List of any Object which extends `Number` such as `List<Double>, List<Float>, List<Short>, List<Integer>`.

Now coming to your question, when you say a List is of Type `<? extends Student>` and add Student1() to it, the compiler is not able to verify whether the type is correct or not and it breaks the compile time safety. (Because ? is an unknown type). Normally you cannot add anything to a `List` having a bounded wildcard as its type (except null and except if you follow a rather complicated process). So either you can declare your list as of type `Student` but that will mean that your first add statement would not throw an error.

In most practical scenarios, this kind of case is handled by making Student `abstract` and implementing all the common functionality in the abstract class while declaring your list as of type `Student`.

Also if you ever want to add to a bounded wildcard type, you can write a helper function like this and call it in your method (This also accepts Student as valid type. There's no way to force a Type to extend something because type resolution is always inclusive in Java):

```
private <Student, S extends Student> void addd(List<Student> l, S element) {
    l.add(element);
}
```

and call it as:

```
addd(emp, new Student());
addd(emp, new Student1());
addd(emp, new Student3());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "List<? extends Student>" when you want to access the existing elements of List.

Use "List<? super Student>" when you want to set the elements to the List.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.